# Loading Tensorflow Graph in other file not giving the same accuracy

Tags: session, tensorflow, inference

I trained a CNN in Tensorflow and it tested with 92% accuracy. I saved it as a typical ckpt file.

```
session = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))
session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
<TRAINING ETC>
saver.save(session, save_path_name)
```

In a different file, I want to run inference, so I called the meta-graph as explained in the documentation:

```
face_recognition_session = tf.Session()
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(<PATH TO META FILE>, clear_devices=True)

saver.restore(face_recognition_session, <PATH TO CKPT FILE>)

graph = tf.get_default_graph()
x = graph.get_tensor_by_name('input_variable_00:0')
y = graph.get_tensor_by_name('output_variable_00:0')
```

When performing inference or testing it anew, the accuracy drops to 3%.

Am I overlooking anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning the wrong method to `saver`.  From the [TF Guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model) you can see that you want to init session and then upload through `tensorflow.train.Saver()`.

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
# Create some variables.
x = tf.get_variable("input_variable_00:0", [x_shape])
y = tf.get_variable("output_variable_00:0", [y_shape])

saver = tf.train.Saver()

# Use the saver object normally after that.
with tf.Session() as sess:
  # Initialize v1 since the saver will not.
  saver.restore(sess, <PATH TO CKPT FILE>)

  print("x : %s" % x.eval())
  print("y : %s" % y.eval())
```

I would also recommend looking into [freezing and exporting your graphs](https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/tool_developers/) as a `GraphDef` if you want to have consistent inference results.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! tf.get_variable gives "ValueError: 'input_variable_00:0' is not a valid scope name". I am loading from a separate file, so get_variable wouldn't recognize the variable by name, right?

Comment: As for freezing the graph, the inference time is drastically slower with pb graphs than with ckpt graphs...

Comment: As I understand it, your `checkpoint` is holding all variables with respective weights and biases.  Your `meta_graph` contains the architecture of the model.  A .pb `GraphDef` is more-or-less the combination of the two.  While training, `checkpoints` and `meta_graphs` are useful for keeping track of the model as you optimize.  But for inference on a fully trained net, the .pb model seems best.

You can look into optimizing your model for inference for speeding up the process [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/tools/optimize_for_inference.py)

Comment: @user3337758 Regarding the error thrown by tf.get_variable, I would verify the tensor name actually exists in the checkpoint file.  This can be done using the [inspect checkpoint](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.10/tensorflow/python/tools/inspect_checkpoint.py) tool as a script or something like:

        `from tensorflow.python.tools.inspect_checkpoint import print_tensors_in_checkpoint_file
    print_tensors_in_checkpoint_file(
        file_name=<PATH TO CKPT FILE>,
        tensor_name='',
        all_tensors=True,
        all_tensor_names=True)`